# Why its taking so long to update

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, csv

I have a CSV file with 22000 Rows. For first time, i read all rows from csv file and add them into database using Entity Framework `db.SaveChanges()` where save changes takes 45 seconds. Then next time it reads all records and only add new records and update existing and this takes 2 minutes...
what is best way to insert bulk records?

Comment: When adding only new records and updating existing records a lot more work has to be done than simply inserting 22,000 rows.

Comment: Do you append new rows to the csv file or pick new rows from new csv ?

Comment: Simply bulk insert all of your rows into a staging table in sql-server and then do the update, insert, delete operations there. Never insert/Bulk Insert data directly into your actual tables. CSV files can have all sorts of garbage data in them.

Comment: The best way is don't bulk insert.  Read a row and insert a row.  Is the a need to load all 22,000 before you can process.   Read a row and update or skip.

Comment: This will be automatic process. the client will upload file to a specific folder and system will read file, each row and compare it to database and then insert. Its not bulk insert, it Verify Model for each field.

Answer (score 0):

When saving with the EF, there are 3 disticnt actions that occur and they are very different in speed. Inserts and deletes are done in a single call to SQL server but updates are done one record at a time so it can check for concurrency issues and report back to you which entities failed an why.

If you want to stick with using the EF, you should always INSERT and then do a MERGE (SQL command) on the server. You can also do the MERGE from a sqlcommand in C# if you dont have the ability to create a stored procedure.

The best option and fastest is to use BULK INSERT, if you can.